# How to catch SAML response in saml authentication with react application

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, saml

We are trying to implement SAML authentication with React App where we are using Azure Directory as IDP, when the user gets authenticated UI gets SAML response in HTTP post request payload. But on the client-side (React) we are not able to read this request payload.

Answer (score 2):

[Azure AD will post the SAML response to the Redirect URI of the SP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol). In order to process it you will need server-side logic. You can enable SSR for React or create and API that handles the auth callback and forwards the results to the SPA.

Take a look to [Simple React and Express app SAML login by Okta](https://github.com/seifeldeen92/React-Okta-SAML) for a React SPA + Node.js/Express API sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can study [SAML single sign-on for on-premises applications with Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-on-premises-apps), For react [Configure authentication in a sample React single-page application by using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app).

Video reference for [Simple React and Express app SAML login by Okta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUL59SKiwmE) using React+node.js